# cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'System.MulticastDelegate?'

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
EventCallback callback = new EventCallback(null, tagInfo.RemoveTagAction);
EventCallback<IItemFlyweight> click = EventCallback.Factory.Create<IItemFlyweight>(this, callback);
```

The first line hits the following error in the compiler (this used to compile):

```
Error: D:\a\LouisHowe\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Shared\ItemTagBox.razor.cs(66,54): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'System.MulticastDelegate?' [D:\a\LouisHowe\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\LouisHowe.web.csproj]
```

The `tagInfo.RemoveTagAction`, which is in a 3rd party library and therefore I can't change it, is:

```
public Action RemoveTagAction { get; internal set; }
```

This code used to compile (I think the most recent Visual Studio update brought down a more recent C# compiler?) and run fine. How can I write this to work?

Comment: Note: Yes there are numerous posts here about this error. But they are answered by changing the method signature. In this case RemoveTagAction is in a library and I can't change it.

Comment: If that comment helps understanding the context of the question its perfectly suitable to be in the question right?

Comment: Try `EventCallback.Factory.Create<IItemFlyweight>(this, tagInfo.RemoveTagAction);` The method `Create` creates an EventCallback from an Action.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that did it - THANK YOU. If you make that an answer, and explain why in the answer, happy to accept it (and curious for the explanation). TIA